# Freebase evaluating which fields can be right for a popularity sort heuristic

Tags: google-api, nlp, wikipedia, freebase, dbpedia

I'm trying to fetch subsets of freebase. For a couple of types, I mostly want the most popular entities. For example  when I'm trying to fetch the most popular movies, I want the top 2k most popular movies. I see there is no popularity rank, but whenever I'm trying to limit/sort by things like estimated_budget or gross_revenue I get a very small result set. Is there any way to evaluate which fields might be actually relevant and not just a field that is used in a very low percentage of results?

An example of a simple movies query:

```
[{
  "type": "/film/film",
  "limit": 10,
  "name": null,
  "id": null
}]
```

Question is which `"sort"` option should I consider, to make it sort by some sort of popularity heuristic?

Answer (score 0):

See this page:

http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Search_Cookbook#Scoring_and_Ranking

It says:

Freebase entities have an inherent relevance score (ranking) computed during indexing that is function of its inbound and outbound link counts in Freebase and Wikipedia

You can also add other constraints or scores, as it is explained in the previous page.

The 'relevance scores' are only available while creating the graph, and are not available while using it. Instead, as it is mentioned in the link "results are always sorted by the final score, highest score first". And the score is combination of several scores, and you get to choose the type of the score, e.g. scoring: freebase, etc.

Comment: That looks interesting, but I'm not seeing how to access this field through MQL. Added a simple query example to my question, any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "this field"?

Comment: You've mentioned `Freebase entities have an inherent relevance score ` - how do I tell the MQL query to sort the result by the `inherent relevance score` (which I'd assume should be a property of all type, but not seeing such)

Comment: I think these the 'relevance scores' are only available while creating the graph, and are not available while using it. Instead, as it is mentioned in the link "results are always sorted by the final score, highest score first". And the score is combination of several scores, and you get to choose the type of the score, e.g. scoring: freebase, etc.

Comment: Isn't that only true for the search API? They've written this: `If you do not include a sort directive in a query then Metaweb makes not guarantees about the order in which results are returned. If you don't ask for the data to be sorted, you should treat the result as an unordered set of values rather than an ordered list` http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/index.php?title=MQL_directives&oldid=5639

Comment: Yeah, sure; how else you want to get the data?